# Users can create SSRS subscriptions but can't edit them

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2016

I'm using SSRS 2016. Users can successfully create subscriptions to reports but if they go back to update a parameter (change a date range for example), it throws a "delivery error has occurred" message when they try to save. When you look in the logs, you see the full error below:

> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!reportserverwebapp!49f!07/18/2017-07:44:41::
>   e ERROR: [4cngitdf]: OData exception occurred:
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: A delivery error has
>   occurred. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.DeliveryErrorException:
>   A delivery error has occurred. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InvalidExtensionParameter:
>   One of the extension parameters is not valid for the following reason:
>   The account you are using does not have administrator privileges. A
>   subscription cannot be created for xxxx@xxxx.com.

It appears they have valid permissions to create their own report subscriptions but not to edit their own subscriptions.

We have two security groups setup... Administrators with the Content Manager role and Users with the Browser role. I am in the Administrator's group and I can add and edit subscriptions just fine.

How can I make this so users can edit their own subscriptions (but no one else) without giving them the same permissions I have (I don't want users to be able to edit the reports or data sources so I can't make them Admin's too).

Or is this just maybe a bug in SSRS that I can't work around? Users can even delete their own subscriptions so I've been having them delete and recreate them, but it would be much nicer if they could actually edit them instead. Odd too that it allows them to add and delete but not edit.

Comment: Have you checked out Report Builder and Publisher roles?

Comment: Publisher  - May publish reports and linked reports to the Report Server.

Report Builder - May view report definitions.

I definitely don't want users to have Publisher permissions based on the description in SSRS. Report Builder says they can view report definitions but the name "Report Builder" seems to imply they can build reports, which I don't want them to be able to do either. 

I just want them to be able to edit their own subscriptions and otherwise the normal Browser role works fine.

Comment: I have a similar issue on SSRS 2012. We changed the service that runs SSRS, now users can't edit their old schedules. This seems to be because the  sysjobs.owner_sid does not match the current service.

Comment: That information I suspect is in whatever you named the database for your reports. You might be able to manually edit it through SSMS to fix that. Just a thought. I've resolved a few issues with subscriptions myself doing this.